# How to create a script in Debian to check if the MySQL proccess went down?

Tags: mysql, debian

For some reason, MySQL goes down very often.

I would like to learn how to make a script that would check **If** MySQL is down and if so **then** start it again using `service mysql start`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about finding out why MySQL is going down? look in /var/lib/mysql/*.err for details .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install and use monit

http://mmonit.com/monit/

You can monitor the mysql process and if it is down monit can restart it for you.. a sample config might look like

```
check process mysql with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   group database
   start program = "service mysql start"
   stop program = "service mysql stop"
   if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 protocol mysql then restart
   if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```